# Cross Validated as a migration target

Tags: feature-request

I propose that it would be useful to have Cross Validated as an additional choice in the **Closing > Off-Topic > Migration** dialog box.

Comment: Can you justify why we need it? The [stats](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) don't indicate any pressing need... The first migration in the past three months was the one I did 5 mins ago.

Comment: @rm-rf many questions would be also migrated to [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) is it were on the highly restricted "migration list".  Now, seriously, that restriction and the lack of some [highly needed close reasons](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1014/193) are clearly a model limitation and far from a feature.

Comment: @rm-rf. Then your position is that flagging posts that would be more appropriately be posted on Cross Validation is good enough?

Comment: @m_goldberg For now, yeah. Unless we have sufficient migration traffic from here to CV, this request will be declined by the SE folks. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3853) for the discussion and resolution when [math.se] tried to set up a migration path to our site.

Comment: @rm-rf. Very edifying link. Thanks.

Comment: @R.M. Can this option be reconsidered ([111220](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111220)). Mathematica has added a ton of functionality for probability and theoretical statistics. I this it is a reasonable migration target.

Comment: @Edmund Please read my comments above — the situation still hasn't changed. We have migrated only 1 question to CV in the past 90 days and even that was rejected. There simply isn't a need for this migration channel. Even the question at hand is probably not a good fit for them. [math.se] appears to be a better destination than CV. BTW, I'm not the one that controls whether this happens or not... moderators have no such powers. I'm just playing the devil's advocate here and trying to prod you/others into producing more convincing evidence :)

Comment: Also, Mathematica is a kitchen sink... they have functionality that could justify migration to [biology.se] ([example](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/11/11/dissecting-the-new-anatomy-content-in-the-wolfram-language/)), [datascience.se], [physics.se], [movies.se] ([example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovieData.html)), [travel.se] ([example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LocationsPathsAndRouting.html))... ;) The presence or absence of a functionality in the software isn't sufficient grounds for opening/requesting a migration channel, IMO.

Comment: @R.M. You are saying what you believe is not sufficient grounds: What would you consider sufficient grounds?

Comment: @Edmund 1 successful migration/week would be a reasonable starting point, I think.